# multiple Mapkit annotations with showdetails how do I load details for each annotation?

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I got my map working fine with multiple annotations in an NSMuttableArray, MyAnnotations display fine with a title and subtitle and a rightcalloutbutton linked to a view with action @selector showDetails. However how do I load details for each annotation into that view? i.e if someone clicks empire state building it displays info about itself into that view, and someone clicks Chrysler building it also displays details about itself in this view.

I have been searching for ways for sometime however i cant seem to figure it out here is a snippet of my rootviewcontroller.m

if it helps all my annotations are named so on and so forth

```
[mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation1];
[mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation2];
[mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation3];
[mapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation4];
```

with corresponding

```
MyAnnotation* myAnnotation1=[[MyAnnotation alloc] init];

myAnnotation1.coordinate=theCoordinate1;
myAnnotation1.title=@"Asda";
myAnnotation1.subtitle=@"Kimberley Way, TN240SE";



- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    NSLog(@"welcome into the map view annotation");

    // if it's the user location, just return nil.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    // try to dequeue an existing pin view first
    static NSString* AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
    MKPinAnnotationView* pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc]
                                     initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
    pinView.animatesDrop=YES;
    pinView.canShowCallout=YES;
    pinView.pinColor=MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;

    //differnt colored pins based on title name

    if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Asda"])

        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;

    else if ([[annotation title] isEqualToString:@"Ashford Football Club"])

        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;

    UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [rightButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(showDetails:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;



    UIImageView *profileIconView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile.png"]];
    pinView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = profileIconView;
    [profileIconView release];

    return pinView;
}


-(IBAction)showDetails:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"Annotation Click");
    self.userProfileVC.title=((UIButton*)sender).currentTitle;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.userProfileVC animated:YES];
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out I declared a label in my detailsview class whick is called userProfileVC then used the below if statement to pass the information text to the correct label for each annotation.

```
-(IBAction)showDetails:(id)sender{

    NSLog(@"Annotation Click");
    self.userProfileVC.title=((UIButton*)sender).currentTitle;
    if([((UIButton*)sender).currentTitle isEqualToString:@"Asda"])
        self.userProfileVC.label.text= @"Glass, Paper, Cans, Textiles, Card, Shoes and Books";
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKAnnotationView/rightCalloutAccessoryView), your map's delegate should receive the message `mapView:annotationView:calloutAccessoryControlTapped:` when the button is tapped. This hands you the MKAnnotationView instance that was tapped, which has an `annotation` property to give you the corresponding annotation. You should make use of that instead of trying to use an action on the button directly.

Comment: Ok cool thanks I got a UIAlertView to display for each annotation using the below but how do I load say a different Image for each annotation that gets loaded onto the view as opposed to this alert? - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:

Answer (score 0):

You could do lik this.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [self addressLocation:address];
region.span=span;
region.center=location;
Annotation *addAnno= [[Annotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:location title:address subtitle:subaddres];
[annotations addObject:addAnno];
```

Therefore in Annotation you had delegate method title and subtitle-(NSSTring)title{, using this you can get your title and subtitle when you click appropriate Annotation.

in Annotation

```
  -(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c title:(NSString*)tit subtitle:(NSString*)sub{

 mTitle=tit;


mSubTitle=sub;

return self;
```

}